# In d3 selection method chaining, how can I reference the values of the selected element?

Tags: d3.js

I have a simple horizontal bar chart, and I'm trying to place an image to the left of each horizontal bar to serve as a label for the bar.

At this point in the script, the bars have been created and are displayed. [image: horizontal bar chart]

I've taken a code sample for adding the labels to the right of the bars (which are included in the image) and tried to update it to place an image to the left.

```
    bars.append("image")
        .attr("class", "bar_image")
        //y position of the image is halfway down the bar
        .attr("y", function(d){
            return y(d.Candidate) + y.rangeBand() / 2 + 4;
        })
        //x position to left of bar
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return -10;
        })
        .attr('xlink:href', function(d){
            return "/static/images/yang.png";
        })
```

My understanding here is that I'm selecting each of the 'bar' elements and appending an image (which is the same image for all right now while I work on placement).

I'm setting the y attribute of the image element to midrange of each y range. This is how the label on the right has its y attr set. x, for now I'm just setting to left of the bar. Then I set the actual href to the image.

My problem now has to do with SIZING the image, and I'd like to be able to set its height/width dynamically based on the height of the 'bar' elements. These heights are obviously dependent on how many bars there are (this graph should scale up or down to any number of people)

[image: chart with image added to bars]

Obviously the positioning isn't perfect, but for now I'd just be happy being able to resize the height/width attributes of the image based on the height of the bars in the chart.

Is there a way to reference in the selection and method chaining the attributes of the elements being selected?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly what I was looking for, but I can set the

```
attr("height", x)
```

of the image element using the same function that sets the height attribute of the bars

```
.attr("height", y.rangeBand())
```

Comment: I'd say that this is exactly what you're looking for.